# Firebase is not uplodaing data to the database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-services, angularfire2

I'm working on an Angular+Firebase project. I'm trying to upload my data to the firebase database. But I'm getting an error while doing do. Below is my FirebaseService Code.

```
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';﻿
import { AngularFireObject, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {
  listings ;
  listing: Observable<any[]>;
  folder: any;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.folder = 'listingimages';
   }

  getListings(){

      this.listings = this.db.list('/listings').snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
        return actions.map(action => ({ key: action.key, ...action.payload.val() }));
      })
      return this.listings;
  }

  getListingDetails(id){
    this.listing = this.db.object('/listings/'+id).valueChanges() as Observable<Listing[]>;
    return this.listing;

  }

  addListing(listing){
    //Create Root Reference     
        let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    for(let selectedFile of [(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('image')).files[0]]){
      let path = `/${this.folder}/${selectedFile.name}`;
      let iRef = storageRef.child(path);
      iRef.put(selectedFile).then((snapshot) => {
        listing.image = selectedFile.name;
        listing.path = path;
        console.log(this.listings);
        return this.listings.push(listing);

        });
    }
  }

}

interface Listing{
    $key?: string;
    title?: string;
    type?: string;
    image?: string;
    city?: string;
    owner?: string;
    bedrooms?: string
}
```

The screenshot of the error which appears in console is as below :[image]

I'm not getting why it is showing undefined error?

Comment: `listings` is `undefined`... intialize it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to initialize it but now a new error shows up. Observable<any[]> is not assignable to 'any[]'.

Comment: Can you change: "this.listing = this.db.object('/listings/'+id).valueChanges() as Observable<Listing[]>" to: "this.listing = this.db.object('/listings/'+id).valueChanges() as Listing[]"?

Answer (score 1):

`this.listings` is only being assigned in your `getListings` and `getListingDetails` methods.  But you're accessing it in `addListing`.  What's probably happening is that you're calling `addListing` before you ever call one of the other methods.

If you want to call those methods in any order, you're going to have to find another way to write to the database that doesn't depend on something else happening earlier.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I thought 'listings' property needs to be initialize first. I tried to go with that but a new error showed up :Observable<any> is not assignable to 'any[]'. Could you help here ? How should I initialize it ?